# Compass directory variables

Tags: css, sass

In the Compass documentation (http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) a couple of variables are defined, which can be used to define directories for images, fonts, js, etc.. With the Compass URL helpers (http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url), I can create relative paths.

What I'm confused about though is which variable from the config is being used. Lets take images as an example. With images, I'm able to define:

- images_dir
- images_path
- http_images_path

Lets say, for example, that I have the following vars created in my config.rb:

```
images_dir = "images"
images_path = "assets/images"
http_images_path = "http://www.example.com/assets/images"
```

What does Compass output in CSS when I have a SCSS file like:

```
body {
  image-url("foobar.jpg");
}
```

Can someone tell me which variable is used when and what the purpose of defining three variables is?

Comment: My config.rb is a little different.  I only have a variable for `images_dir`, and another setting for `relative_assets` (boolean).  Have you looked at your compiled CSS to see what the actual output is?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can add only one of these. I'm only curious what the order of variable execution is. When does Compass use what var?

Comment: Test it and find out?